# How to customize the web service response using jax-ws and wsgen?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, wsgen

I am trying to deploy a small web service using jax-ws and wsgen and cannot get the output to match the desired format.

How do I declare the web method & and the response class with jaxb annotations to get the response look like the below?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:SubmitionAcknowledgement xmlns:ns2="http://ws.testService/">
        <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
        <IOReference>123456789</IOReference>
    <m:SubmitionAcknowledgement>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

so far the closest that I've got to was:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:SubmitionAcknowledgement xmlns:ns2="http://ws.testService/">
        <SubmitionAcknowledgement>
            <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
            <IOReference>123456789</IOReference>
        </SubmitionAcknowledgement>
    <m:SubmitionAcknowledgement>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it myself by adding the below to the web service impl.
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)

This stripped out 1 wrapper from both request and response, so all I had to do was put an additional wrapper onto the request.